# Laravel 5.2 Post 302 redirect to GET

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, routes, http-status-code-302

My problem is that my POST request always redirects to GET after error 302

Here's my routes file :

```
Route::auth();
...
Route::post('/personnalite/creer', 'PersonnaliteController@creerPost')->name('personnaliteCreerPost');
Route::get('/personnalite/creer', 'PersonnaliteController@creerGet')->name('personnaliteCreerGet');
...
```

When I delete the get route befort  posting, laravel  routing fails.
I can see post request before redirect in my web brouter dev tool

Here's my middelware, which is registered in 'web' middelwareGroups.
It just checks that the route is allowed for user role (ACL rules are registered  in a config file)

```
class MyAclMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $myAcl = App::offsetExists('MyAcl') ? App::make('MyAcl') : null;
        if($myAcl) {
            if(Auth::guest()) {
                $myAcl->setRole(0);
            } else {
                $myAcl->setRole(Auth::user()->role);
            }
            if($myAcl->isNotAllowed('route.' . Route::getRoutes()->match($request)->getName())) {
                return redirect()->route('erreur', ['id' => 0]);        
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Here's my form blade template :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Créer une personnalité politique</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ @Form::open(['route' => 'personnaliteCreerPost', 'files' => true]) }}
                        @include('personnalite.subviews.formInfosGenerales')
                        {{ Form::submit('Créer') }}
                    {{ @Form::close() }}
                    @include('personnalite.subviews.listePersonnalites')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@enduction
```

Other out of the box laravel forms  and controllers  for Login... work fine.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: If oyu put a die('here'); in the creerPost method does it ever display?

Comment: Also try being explicit in the Form::open call put 'method' => 'post' into the parameters and see if that changes anything

Comment: For those who have upgraded Laravel recently, check the syntax of your middleware in your controllers. It likely needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED !

The problem was due to bad form validation logic in my controller (insufficient test => no form validation => redirect to previous form)

Shame on me

Answer (score 2):

The 302 redirect is Laravel's (non-ajax) default validation failure.  You can get some control over it by doing it like this:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }
```

By capturing the failure and then manually redirecting, you can be sure what's coming back to your page.  Also, those errors will not show up on your page unless you have some code to display them - they are held in a session variable.  So it can look like you are just returning to the page in some strange circular route, when in fact there are errors to be displayed.  The plural, withErrors, are good for a series of validation errors, and can be displayed under the appropriate field in the blade template like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('first_name'))
    <span class="text-danger">{!! $errors->first('first_name') !!}</span>
@endif
```

Then you have at the top of your page, something like this:

```
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
   </div>
@endif
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Which catch custom error messages sent from your controller like:

```
return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Profile updated');
```

or

```
return redirect()->back()->with("error","New Password does not match the password confirmation field. Please make sure they are the same.");
```

Note the one letter difference between "errors" and "error".  That can trip you up if you make a typo.

And just to be complete, a status 422 is what you get back from validation failure via an ajax call to your controller.  Laravel does so much for you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for other users that having the same problem cannot solve it with the solution above:

Make sure that the form fields names for instance `<input type="text" name="document_name">` **(document_name)**, match the names of the rules fields declared in the model. 
`public static $rules = ['document_name' => 'required|string'];`

It doesn't throw any errors, nothing in the logs, it just redirects to the form, therefore the difficulty to find the problem.

For me, that was the problem, coincides with your reason "bad form validation logic".